# Close pop-up box with mouse click outside boundary

Tags: javascript, html

I have made this homepage. That has pop up boxes with log-in fields. When there is a pop up the background is dimmed. But the pop up should close if the user clicks any where outside the boundaries of the box. I have created the function closeOverlay, which works when the user hits "esc" on the keyboard, but when the user clicks outside the boundary of the box nothing happens. How can I make it so it works in both cases, when the user hits escape, or takes the mouse outside of the box boundaries and clicks

This is the HTML code

```
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="LAb2css.css">
</head>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {


        setInterval(move, 10000);

    }



    function move() { //makes the box move in relation to the box div
              var d = document.getElementById('moveQuestion');
              var boxh = document.getElementById('boxDIV').clientHeight - 100; //keeps the image in the box by subtracting height
              var boxw = document.getElementById('boxDIV').clientWidth - 100; //keeps the image in the box by subtracting the width

              document.onmousemove = function calc(e) {
                var x = e.clientX ;
                var y = e.clientY;

                if (x < boxw) {
                    d.style.left = x +'px';
                }

                if (y < boxh) {
                    d.style.top = y +'px';
                }

              };
          };


function signin() { //displays the sign in form
            var lg = document.getElementById('login');
            var ov = document.getElementById('BackDIV');
            ov.style.display = 'block';
            lg.style.display = 'block';
          };

function join() { //calls the join form for users to register

            var lg = document.getElementById('signup');
            var ov = document.getElementById('BackDIV');
            ov.style.display = 'block';
            lg.style.display = 'block';
            activeForm = 1; //sets the active form counter to 1; a form is active
        };
function recoverPass() { //displays the recoverPassword form for the user to recover password

            var ov = document.getElementById('BackDIV');
            ov.style.display = 'block';

            var rp = document.getElementById('recoverPassword');
            rp.style.display = 'block';
             //sets the active form counter to 1; a form is active
        };    





         function closeOverlay() { // function closes the black transparent overlay div by setting the display properties of all the forms to none 
            var ov = document.getElementById('BackDIV');
            var rp = document.getElementById('recoverPassword');
            var lg = document.getElementById('login');
            var sg = document.getElementById('signup');

            ov.style.display = 'none';
            rp.style.display = 'none';
            lg.style.display = 'none';
            sg.style.display = 'none';
          };




     function closeOverlay() { // function closes the black transparent overlay div by setting the display properties of all the forms to none 
            var ov = document.getElementById('BackDIV');
            var rp = document.getElementById('recoverPassword');
            var lg = document.getElementById('login');
            var sg = document.getElementById('signup');

            ov.style.display = 'none';
            rp.style.display = 'none';
            lg.style.display = 'none';
            sg.style.display = 'none';
          };



             function closeOverlay() { // function closes the black transparent overlay div by setting the display properties of all the forms to none 
            var ov = document.getElementById('BackDIV');
            var rp = document.getElementById('recoverPassword');
            var lg = document.getElementById('login');
            var sg = document.getElementById('signup');

            ov.style.display = 'none';
            rp.style.display = 'none';
            lg.style.display = 'none';
            sg.style.display = 'none';
          };


          document.onkeydown = function(evt) { //makes the escape key to call the closeOverlay() function
            evt = evt || window.event;
            if (evt.keyCode == 27) {
                closeOverlay();
            }
          };



</script>

<body onload = move()>

    <div id="BackDIV">
    </div>

    <p>
        <?php
            // Just for displaying the display type for testing

            echo 'Display type = ' . $display_type . '<br><br>';

            if ($display_type == 'Start') {
                echo 'StartPage<br>';
            }
            else if ($display_type == 'SignIn') {
                echo "StartPage with 'SignIn' popup box<br>"; 
            }
            else if ($display_type == 'Join') {
                echo "StartPage with 'Join' popup box<br>"; 
            }
            else if ($display_type == 'ForgotPassword') {
                echo "StartPage with 'ForgotPassword' popup box<br>"; 
            }
            else {
                echo 'StartPage with no popup box<br>'; 
            }
        ?>
    </p>


    <div id = "main">

        <div id = "dateDIV"><?php $t = time(); echo (date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $t)); ?></div>

        <div id = "titleDIV">
          <h2>Thompson Rivers University - Question/Answers</h2>                    
        </div>

        <div id ="dopDownDIV">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href = "#"><img src="images/responsive_menu.png" title="MENU" alt="Menu" id="MenuIMG" height="50PX" width="50px" /></a>
                <ul>
                  <li><a href="#" onclick = "signin()">SIGN IN</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#" onclick="join()">JOIN</a></li>

                    <li><a href="#" onclick="recoverPass()">FORGOT PASSWORD</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>       
        </div>

        <div id="boxDIV"> <a href ="#"><img src ="images/question-mark.png" id="moveQuestion" title= "Image moving In Box" alt="ImgInbox" height = "100px" width = "100px"</a></div>

        <div id= "BottomDIV">
            <a href = "http://cs.tru.ca" target="_blank"> About Us </a>
        </div>

    </div>

<!--Div for Signup form on click -->
 <div id="signup" onclick="closeOverlay()">
            <form action="main.html" method="get" autocomplete="on">
                <input type="text" name="username" autofocus><br /><p>Your email address</p>
                <input type="password" name="password"><br /><p>Password</p>
                <br /><br /><br />
                <input id="formButton" type="submit" value="Join">
                <a href="StartPage.html">
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel"/>
                </a>
            </form>
 </div>


<!--DIv for recoverPassword -->

<div id="recoverPassword" onclick="closeOverlay()">
            <!--<h1>Recover Password</h1> -->
            <form action="main.html" method="get" autocomplete="on">
                <input type="text" name="recoveremail" placeholder="The email address you registered with" autofocus><br /><p>Username (or email address)</p>

                <input id="formButton" type="submit">
                <a href="StartPage.html">
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel"/>
                </a>
            </form>
        </div>  

<!--Div for Login -->
    <div id="login" onclick="closeOverlay()">

            <form action="controller.php" method="post" autocomplete="on" >
                <input type='hidden' name='command' value='SignIn'>
                <input type="text" name="user" autofocus value="<?php echo $username ?>"> <?php echo $error_msg_username; ?> ><br />                            <p>Username (or email address)</p>
                <input type="password" name="pass" value="<?php echo $password ?>"> <?php echo $error_msg_password ?> ><br /><p>Password</p>
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" id="formButton" value="Sign In" >
                <a href="StartPage.html">
                    <input type="button" value="Cancel"/>
                </a>


            </form>
        </div>





</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does this question have to do with jQuery? It doesn't look like you aren't using it. And why do you have multiple 'closeOverlay' functions? To answer your question: can you not just add an `eventListener` to your `BackDIV`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div id="BackDIV" onclick="closeOverlay();"></div>
```

Comment: I added your code into the top script sections of my HTML, but it doesn't seem to do anything :(

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't work, can you set up your example in a codepen or jsfiddle so I can see it working?

Comment: When you click any of the links in the drop down, it only works by "esc" to exit them not by clicking outside with the mouse. Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/hzfs4p7a/ (sorry the images aren't working)

Comment: When you go over the Menu on the top left, click either of the 3 links. The pop up only closes if we hit esc on the keyboard, not by clicking outside the pop up area

Comment: Edited my answer, just confirmed this is working in your jsfiddle. Try that instead.

Comment: Now when I click on the pop up window to enter a username or password. The pop up closes. The pop up should only close when user clicks outside of the pop up boundary, not inside the pop up

Comment: Make sure that the popup has a higher z-index than the overlay, set the overlay to have a z-index of 0 and the popup anything higher than that and try it.

Answer (score 0):

like this ? add an event listener to the window, remove the confirm if you want .

```js
var pop=document.getElementById('over');window.addEventListener('click',function(){
  confirm('close popup')?
  pop.style.display="none":pop.style.display="block";
  
});
```

```css
#over{min-width:80%;min-height:  100px;background-color:red;}
```

```html
<div id="over">v</div>
```

Comment: pretend the red area is the pop up

Comment: I added your code, except the "confirm" portion. But after adding it, none of my pop-ups display at all when I click the links for them

Comment: my bad, the minute you are clicking the window they are being closed,change it to `window.addEventListener('click',function(){if(document.getElementById('BackDIV'){closeOverlay(); } } );`if they're open it'll close.